# Does spring-boot support any dynamic OLAP report generation tool?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, olap, olap-cube, olap4j

I need to add OLAP report support into my existing spring boot web application. I have come across multiple BI tools like BIRT, JasperServer Report and Saiku but for all of them, I have to use an already created cube. In case, there is any modification in data, it will not reflect in my report.

Is there any 3rd party tool which can facilitate me to create a cube at runtime or to generate a report by adding data to the cube at runtime?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you've mainly just been looking for OLAP analytics tools and not an OLAP datastore. How about using an RDBMS-styled OLAP datastore like [LinkedIn's Pinot](https://github.com/linkedin/pinot)? Data can be added (albeit "add-only" style) in real-time.

It has a nice [REST and Java client API](https://github.com/linkedin/pinot/wiki/Pinot-Client-API) for doing the analytics you want against that living datastore.